# Crystal reports CSV incorrect generation

Tags: crystal-reports

When setting ExportFormatType.CharacterSeparatedValues crystal report generates every row of data prefixed with column names (Report Headers). Why it does this? How it could be fixed? Usually it is preferred to have single header. For excel export type - generated report looks ok (only single header for all rows).

I am using crystal reports 11.5.3700.0. Visual studio 2008, .net 3.5 sp1

Answer (score 1):

If the type of delimiter is not of concern, you may want to try 'Tab Separate Text (TTX)'.

Comment: unfortunately need comma saparated. the only possible way is to hide header section and insert it to file manually..

Answer (score 1):

You need to check the option to 'Isolate report/page sections' in the export options for that section.